An application of pigeonhole principle in matrix
Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix composed of real numbers where $n \geqslant 2$, satisfying the following conditions: the absolute value of each number is 1, and the sum of all numbers is non-negative. Such a matrix $A$ is referred to as an "n-order non-negative matrix."
For any "5-order non-negative matrix" $A$, let $R(s)$ denote the sum of the numbers in the $s$-th row of $A$ where $1 \leqslant s \leqslant 5$. Prove that there exist $\lbrace i, j, k\rbrace \subseteq \lbrace 1, 2, 3, 4, 5\rbrace$ such that $R(i) + R(j) + R(k) \geqslant 3$.
When $n = 2k$ where $k \in \mathbb{N}^*$, prove that for any "n-order non-negative matrix" $A$, there exist $k$ rows and $k$ columns such that the sum of the $k^2$ numbers at the intersections of these $k$ rows and $k$ columns is not less than $k$.
I know I need to use pigeonhole principle to solve them, but I don't know exactly how it worked. Please tell me what is the main idea of these problems.

@RyszardSzwarc There are not necessarily 3 such rows. For example,
$$
\pmatrix{
1&1&1&1&1\
1&1&-1&-1&-1\
1&1&-1&-1&-1\
1&1&-1&-1&-1\
1&1&-1&-1&-1\
}
$$

@uuh How do you know that the pigeonhole principle is applicable here? Was that information that you got with these questions?

1/ You should make it clear that you have 2 different problems listed here. Ideally, they should be split into 2 posts. $\quad$ 2/ For the first problem, show that each row sum is odd. Then, if the sum of the 3 largest rows is 1, what can we conclude about the sum of all 5 rows? Arguably I didn't use PHP, though its in the spirit of it. (Of course, that's not to say that there isn't a PHP solution.)

@RyszardSzwarc MSE rules/guidelines are that you shouldn't answer in the comments, and you also shouldn't answer posts where OP doesn't show their work.

@CalvinLin OK. I will remove my previous comments.

Have tried to argue by contradiction? What happens if one row contains at least $k$ positive entries ? Can you find appropriate $k$ columns ? What can you say if every row contains at most $k-1$ positive entries ?
